# react-native-router-flux disabling android back button from going back to login screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Using **react-native-router-flux**, after user was success login, I would like to disable the back button from going back to the login screen.
But I can not seem to find a way of getting the current "Scene" or "Stack" and then make some login as:

```
backAndroidHandler={() => {
                        if (currentScene === afterLoginScreeen) {
                         return true;   
                        }
                    }}
```

Did any one manage to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As my experience on react-native-router-flux i had use

> type={ActionConst.RESET} in Scene

```
<Scene duration={0} key="main" component={Main} title="Some Title" type={ActionConst.RESET} />
```

It should what you need to avoid back to Login Screen

[ActionConst and Scene.type explaination](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md#actionconst-and-scenetype-explaination)

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: this only works if the component is already in the stack. If not It will throw an error

Comment: @pikanerd I'm not sure, if it still work on the latest version of `rnrf` because there are many breaking change on latest version of `rnrf `

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me

```
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);        
  }

handleBackButton = () => {
             // Do nothing
             return true;
  };
```

Update: as componentWillMount has been deprecated useEffect hook should be used instead

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<Scene key="Screen1" type="replace" component={Screen1} />
```